# Program crashing when trying to create multiple threads

Tags: multithreading, haskell, concurrency

I have the following program:

```
module Main where

import System (getArgs)
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Monad

spawn left id = do
   right <- newEmptyMVar
   forkIO (thread id left right) 
   return right

thread id left right = go 
   where go = do l <- takeMVar left
                 putStrLn (show id)
                 putMVar right ()

main = do
   args <- getArgs
   if null args then
      putStrLn "Arguments not supplied"
   else do
      initial <- newEmptyMVar
      final <- foldM spawn initial [1..(read (head args))]
      putMVar initial ()
      takeMVar final
```

As you can see, it just creates a bunch of threads: each thread prints an integer, but the second thread waits for the first before printing, the third waits for the second and so on. Let us not discuss the usefulness of this program (it's just an exercise).

Now, when I try to create one million threads, the program is killed with SIGKILL. I'd like to know the reason of this. Is it because of too many MVars?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every thread that's created requires its own program stack. I don't actually know how large of a stack Haskell uses for its threads, but if it's 4kbytes (which would be terribly small, actually) that's going to be 4GB just for the million stacks. If you're on a 32-bit machine, that's all of addressable memory, so that's obviously not going to work. And typical stack sizes are more like a megabyte!

Comment: Apparently I was fooled by the fact that one of my previous programs did start one million threads, but worked fine. Now I realize that since those threads didn't wait for each other, some of them had already ended by the time the new ones were created.

Comment: So even if it's running out of memory, a SIGKILL is the wrong error message.  It should say that it's out of memory.  You should file a bug report.

Comment: @augustss you can get a SIGKILL from the linux out of memory killer, no? There's really (by design) no way for the runtime to handle that.

Comment: @sclv I cannot believe a program cannot protect itself so won't receive SIGKILL.  Sure, under certain circumstances the signal will be delivered, but the ghc rts should make it never happens.  I call it a bug.

Comment: @augustss: "In contrast to SIGTERM and SIGINT, this signal cannot be caught or ignored, and the receiving process cannot perform any clean-up upon receiving this signal." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGKILL

Comment: @sclv I know very well that SIGKILL cannot be caught. :)  But I had forgotten that Linux is misdesigned and sends SIGKILL to random processes when running out of memory.  It's still a bug, but I'm willing to call it a Linux bug.

Comment: @augustuss -- The oom killer can be neatly managed in production environments. It's just a royal pain that I consider more a job for sysadmins than developers.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the GHC docs](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/runtime-control.html), the initial stack size for each thread is by default 1K, and it can grow on demand to 8M per thread.

You can adjust these numbers by using the RTS options `-k` and `-K`, for example:

```
$ ./Threads 1000000 +RTS -k512 -K1K -s
```

Your program runs fine on my system (64-bit with 6GB RAM), but it does consume over 2GB at its peak.

```
   4,743,629,168 bytes allocated in the heap
   4,368,720,328 bytes copied during GC
   1,043,256,808 bytes maximum residency (11 sample(s))
     221,352,512 bytes maximum slop
            2413 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

  Generation 0:  8707 collections,     0 parallel,  1.46s,  1.59s elapsed
  Generation 1:    11 collections,     0 parallel,  1.72s,  3.16s elapsed

  INIT  time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  MUT   time    5.86s  ( 15.76s elapsed)
  GC    time    3.18s  (  4.75s elapsed)
  EXIT  time    0.08s  (  0.08s elapsed)
  Total time    9.12s  ( 20.59s elapsed)

  %GC time      34.9%  (23.1% elapsed)

  Alloc rate    798,590,769 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  65.1% of total user, 28.9% of total elapsed

./Threads 1000000 +RTS -K1K -s  9.12s user 3.92s system 62% cpu 20.815 total
```